# File not found for module, but the file very certainly is there

Tags: rust

I have a project with a file tree that looks like this:

```
src
├── structure.rs
├── fn_lib.rs
└── main.rs
```

I import fn_lib.rs into main.rs fine, however I am told by the compiler that the file is not found when I try to import fn_lib.rs into structure.rs.

```
//main.rs
mod fn_lib;
use fn_lib::*;

mod structure;
use structure::My_struct;
```

```
//structure.rs
mod fn_lib;
use fn_lib::*;
```

Most notably, through trial and error, I have noticed that when I remove the import of structure.rs into main.rs, The code compiles.

The compiler suggests that I create the file under src/structure/fn_lib.rs, And I don't understand why it wants that, nor does it seem to be accessible from main.rs.

Comment: try using an IDE. they can fix your import issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing declarations of modules with `mod` and importing of things with `use`. You declare your module just once, for example in `main.rs` with `mod fn_lib` and that's enough. You don't need to put `mod fn_lib` to the `structure.rs` or any other file. In other files you only import things from this module with `use`.

And you can take a look at [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/split.html) to see how file hierarchy works.

If you want to insert contents of file `fn_lib.rs` as module `fn_lib` in another module `structure` you have to place it inside `structure/fn_lib.rs`, that's how it works.
To use your `fn_lib` in `structure` module you just import necessary things with use:

```
//structure.rs
use crate::fn_lib::<symbol_name>
```

Here you import from `crate::` since you attached module at crate level (by declaring it in `main.rs`)